# how to increase virtual memory for each one on linux ?(command line)

Tags: linux, shell, memory

I just allocate some virtual memory for each account,

```
 pi@duckpi01 /etc $ ulimit -v 100
pi@duckpi01 /etc $ ulimit -v 200
-bash: ulimit: virtual memory: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
pi@duckpi01 /etc $ ulimit -v 99
pi@duckpi01 /etc $ ulimit -v 101
-bash: ulimit: virtual memory: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
pi@duckpi01 /etc $ ulimit -v 100
-bash: ulimit: virtual memory: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
pi@duckpi01 /etc $ ulimit -v 200
-bash: ulimit: virtual memory: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
pi@duckpi01 /etc $ cd security
pi@duckpi01 /etc/security $ vi limits.conf
Segmentation fault
pi@duckpi01 /etc/security $ sudo ulimit -v 200
Segmentation fault
```

But now I cannot use `ulimit` to allocate memory more than 99. Apparently, 99kbytes is not enough for me to do anything. I use `sudo`, but it does't work. How could I do to fix this problem?

This doesn't work :

```
pi@duckpi01 /etc/security $ sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2048M tmpfs /media/nameme/
Segmentation fault
pi@duckpi01 /etc/security $ sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=500M tmpfs /media/nameme/
Segmentation fault
```

This doesn't work,too:

```
pi@duckpi01 /etc/security $ sudo ulimit -v unlimited
Segmentation fault
pi@duckpi01 ~ $ sudo su
Segmentation fault
pi@duckpi01 ~ $ mkdir -p /media/nameme
Segmentation fault
pi@duckpi01 ~ $ free -m
Segmentation fault
pi@duckpi01 ~ $ sudo ulimit -v
Segmentation fault
pi@duckpi01 ~ $ ulimit -v
99
pi@duckpi01 ~ $ su -u root
Segmentation fault
```

Doesn't work:

```
pi@duckpi01 ~ $ ulimit -c unlimited
pi@duckpi01 ~ $ ulimit -v
99
pi@duckpi01 ~ $ ulimit -v 10000
-bash: ulimit: virtual memory: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
pi@duckpi01 ~ $ ls
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try by RAM disk facility if suppose you have 4GB of RAM than you can use following command

`mount -t tmpfs -o size=2048M tmpfs /media/nameme/`

And maximum utilization of resources.

Comment: It doesn't work:pi@duckpi01 /etc/security $ sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2048M tmpfs /media/nameme/
Segmentation fault
pi@duckpi01 /etc/security $ sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=500M tmpfs /media/nameme/
Segmentation fault

Comment: first you have to create directory like `mkdir -p /media/nameme`

Comment: how much RAM do you have ?

Comment: cannot do this :pi@duckpi01 ~ $ mkdir -p /media/nameme
Segmentation fault

Comment: cannot check anything now: pi@duckpi01 ~ $ free -m
Segmentation fault

Comment: by `sudo ulimit -v` what is the output you see in terminal ?

Comment: see this :pi@duckpi01 ~ $ sudo ulimit -v
Segmentation fault

Comment: If I use "ulimit -v", I will see:pi@duckpi01 ~ $ ulimit -v
      99

Comment: get root access `sudo su ` and then try all commands without sudo

Comment: doesn't work :pi@duckpi01 ~ $ sudo su
Segmentation fault

Comment: try this `ulimit -c unlimited` and for more details refer this link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132192/running-application-ends-with-segmentation-fault

Comment: seems like you need to reboot or logout and re-login to the OS

Answer (score 2):

login as `root` and reset limits:

```
su -u root    
ulimit -v unlimited
```

or logout from current user and login as root:

```
logout
```

Comment: doesn't work:pi@duckpi01 /etc/security $ sudo ulimit -v unlimited
Segmentation fault